# api_key cannot contain whitespace space Stripe

Tags: cart, checkout-page

I have installed Stripe PHP Library and the latest Stripe extensions and getting the error
`api_key cannot contain whitespace`

Steps for installing Stripe.

```
Download extension from https://code.stripe.com/magento/stripe-magento2-latest.tgz

tar -xvf stripe-magento2-latest.tgz

composer require stripe/stripe-php:^7

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Add to cart is also not working showing an error in the browser console.

[image]

Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Methods also not opening.

Answer (score 0):

You are including white space in API key me be white space from beginning or at the end point of API key copy and paste it in notepad than copy it without white space, hope it will help you.

Thankyou

Comment: I added a key then removed it but still got the error. I have removed data from and there is no data in stripe_webhooks DB table.

Comment: Try to clean flush cache and remove static content and use incognito browser

Comment: Done all steps, removed the extension, and re- installed. deployed content, flushed cache, and also using incognito.

Comment: Can you share screenshot? and log

Comment: Here it is log from var/log/exception.log https://tinyurl.com/yz5p7zmb

Comment: [2021-10-26 14:41:37] main.CRITICAL: api_key cannot contain whitespace {"exception":"[object] (Stripe\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): api_key cannot contain whitespace at /cloudclusters/magento/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/BaseStripeClient.php:246)"} []

Comment: It looks like you have made changes in vendor, you need to remove stripe/stripe-php/lib/BaseStripeClient.php:246) strip named module from vendor if you have copy of magento same version than go to same pathe e.g vendor/strip and copy strip and paste it in vendor than try deployment hope this will help you because you have made changes in core files

Comment: Removed stripe extension and stripe php library and then installed both using composer, but still same issue. However, on another site, It is working perfectly.

Comment: No, Don't use composer  just remove /vendor/stripe and copy from backup and paste it in /vendor:
Make sure copy this from same version of magneto which had installed

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/issue-with-stripe-PHP-library/td-p/477995